# Convert char[][] to char**

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have a `char[][]`

```
  char c[2][2]={
    {'a','b'},
    {'c','d'}
  };
```

How can I convert it to `char**`?

The objective here is to use the converted `char**` as an input for a main function, which only accepts `char**` as its input.  Both C/C++ solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Is this for C or C++? Do you want a just a duplicate of your `char [][]` in `char**` **or** do you want to convert to a `char**` array of pointers to **strings**?  (e.g. are you trying to ultimately be able to print the strings with `printf ("%s\n", array[i]);` ?) We have to know what your `main function` does with the `char**` or we are just guessing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you could easily switch from `char[]` to `char*`,  the same is not possible with `char[][]` and `char**`:

- your `char[2][2]` is a 2 dimensional array having all the elements stored contiguously. To access one element, the compiler computes the offset knowing the size of each row.
- `char**` points to an array that contains pointers to char. To access one element, your compiler computes the offset of the pointer in the left-most, load that poitner, then access to the element.

Workaround:

```
char *pc[2]={c[0],c[1]}; 
cout << pc[1][1]<<endl;   // prints out the same as c[1][1]
// you can pass `pc` when a `char**` is needed
```

***Remark:*** this compiles perfectly. However, some functions with an argument like `char **av` expect in reality `av[i]` to be a null terminated c-string.  In this case, although your code would compile, the results might not be what you expect (buffer overflow).

Comment: read the question again, he presumably wants to use null-terminated strings.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes ! I just reallized and added an extra remark.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Good point ! Definitively yes, if the intend is to call `execvp()`/`execvpe()`.  The `main()` function shall by the way not be called from within the programme (Standard, 3.6.1).  In all other cases, it depends of course of the function, and if there's a counter that would identify the last element.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No,  I did not mean null-terminated strings. Not stated in the original question, anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @zell: it is, not directly though. "an input for a main function"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a `char[2][2]` to `char**`, you can only convert it to `char(*)[2]`,

```
char (*p)[2] = c;
```

The above is a pointer to array-of-2-char. Note that you need this `2` and cannot just write `char** p`, since in the latter case you are not able to perform pointer arithmetic (the pointer won't know how many elements to "jump" when incrementing, and you won't be able to address the elements of your array (in this case the rows)).

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the array into the function like this:

```
char c[2][2] = {
    {'a','b'},
    {'c','d'}
};

char* x[] { c[0], c[1] };
func(x); // Assuming something like: void func(char** p);
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Although this answer may explain/illustrate the problem quite well other answers are preferable that recommend creating an *automatic variable* `char*[2];` rather than allocating with `new` as this answer does.

**Original answer:**

The problem is `char c[2][2]` is a contiguous block of `char`. The compiler allocates only 4 `char` objects.

When you build an *array of arrays* (`char** c`) you need to manually allocate an array of *pointers* to `char` and then allocate (or assign) and array of `char` to each of those pointers.

So to *convert* your array `char c[2][2]` to an *array of arrays* you have to first create the array of pointers and then assign the array of the first element of each *array of char* to that.

Something like this:

```
void func(char** c)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
        for(int y = 0; y < 2; ++y)
            std::cout << c[x][y] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    // one contiguous block of 4 chars
    char c[2][2]={
        {'a','b'},
        {'c','d'}
      };

    char** param = new char*[2]; // create your own pointer array
    param[0] = &c[0][0]; // assign the first element of each char array
    param[1] = &c[1][0];

    func(param); // call your func

    delete[] param; // cleanup
}
```

If you have `C++11` you can use a smart pointer to prevent memory leaks if an exception is thrown or someone forgets to `delete`.

```
int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    // one contiguous block of 4 chars
    char c[2][2]={
        {'a','b'},
        {'c','d'}
      };

    // use a smart pointer
    std::unique_ptr<char*[]> param(new char*[2]);
    param[0] = &c[0][0];
    param[1] = &c[1][0];

    func(param.get()); // now if this throws, no memory leak

    // delete[] param; // NO NEED TO DELETE
}
```

Comment: `char *param[2];` would be far superior to `char **param = new char *[2];`

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes I agree. I'll take this down.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok so I can't delete this now, pointing to other answers